# Separate OWL Carousel script

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel-2

I can't get this to work. I need to separate the OWL carousel script into 2 lose items.
(It won't work when I use the "function owlInitialize()" two times)

*The reason is that I made a PageBuilder and need to add the whole script per added carousel item.*

This is the script which does work but it needs to be separated:
I also rather have a different `$(window).width()` for each one.

```
function owlInitialize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 860) {
  
        $('.over-slider').addClass("owl-carousel");
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:false,    
            margin: 30,  
            dots: true,        
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1,           
                },
                680:{
                    items:2,           
                }
            }
        });
  
        $('.diensten-slider').addClass("owl-carousel");
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:false,      
            dots: true,
            margin: 30,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1,           
                },
                680:{
                    items:2,           
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
  
        $('.over-slider.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('destroy');
        $('.over-slider').removeClass("owl-carousel");
  
        $('.diensten-slider.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('destroy');
        $('.diensten-slider').removeClass("owl-carousel");
  
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    owlInitialize();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    owlInitialize();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/wb7pmfqo/9/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/wb7pmfqo/11/

```
function owlInitialize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 860) {  
        $('.over-slider').addClass("owl-carousel");
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:false,    
            margin: 30,  
            dots: true,        
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1,           
                },
                680:{
                    items:2,           
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{  
        $('.over-slider.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('destroy');
        $('.over-slider').removeClass("owl-carousel");
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    owlInitialize();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    owlInitialize();
});

  
// over + diensten slider
function owlInitialize2() {
    if ($(window).width() < 860) {
        $('.diensten-slider').addClass("owl-carousel");
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:false,      
            dots: true,
            margin: 30,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1,           
                },
                680:{
                    items:2,           
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('.diensten-slider.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('destroy');
        $('.diensten-slider').removeClass("owl-carousel");
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    owlInitialize2();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    owlInitialize2();
});
```